# hibernate save of bigdecimal

Tags: java, hibernate, bigdecimal

I have hibernate code , which inserts Bigdecimal number into Db column of type FLOAT. It works generally. However when I try to insert a value 0.00000000009080767
and fetch the object again, I see the returned value is different.

However when I try to insert the value using SQL query directly and then fetch using hibernate load method, I see that the SOP of getAmount method prints the value correctly.

**Code:**

```
Contact contact1 = new Contact("sailesh1117777", "unknown@gmail.com", "Vietnam1", "0904277091",new BigDecimal("0.00000000009080767"));
session.persist(contact1);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
session.close();

session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Contact contact5 = (Contact) session.load(Contact.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(((BigDecimal)contact5.getAmount()).toPlainString());
```

```
<class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
    <id name="id" column="CONTACT_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME"/>
    <property name="email"/>
    <property name="address"/>
    <property name="telephone"/>
       <property name="amount" type="big_decimal"/>

</class>
```

**OUTPUT:** 0.00000000008978076

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, rather than using a comment.

Comment: how to you store the value in the database?

Comment: If the column's type really is FLOAT then that's not a surprise. There is a limit to precision for floating point types and float is one of those with the least precision. There might be other datatypes such as NUMBER which allow you to specify a maximum precision but there's still a limit and 17 fraction digits is already quite high IMO.

Comment: @JordiCastilla, I store the value in DB using hibernate framework.

Comment: I mean ¿which type of data you have in the database to store the `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @Thomas, I do not want to change the column definition from FLOAT to anything else as, this is live in production and has data. Only thing I can do is do code changes , so that i can release it next time to production.

Comment: The data type in DB is FLOAT(126)

Comment: @Thomas, if that is the case , then why inserting through plain SQL query is inserting it with upto 17 decimals ?

Comment: Something wrong here already. If you're using `BigDecimal` in the code, you must have a reason, and the same reason applies to the database. Almost certainly you should be using an appropriately configured `DECIMAL` column type in the database. Conversions like this are always grounds for suspicion.

Comment: Might be a conversion issue along with the precision issue inherent to floating point numbers. Entering it directly via SQL would remove at least one operation that might influence precision. Besides that, are you entirely sure the entity you store gets the id 1?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, everytime i insert data, i always delete the existing data and reinsert, so that i dont need to do any code changes.

Comment: @EJP, Earlier we were using java.lang.Double to store in the DB FLOAT type column.However , there was a requirement to store any value upto 17 decimal precision. And the challenge was that DB column definition cannot be changed , as there is data already in production.

Comment: You cannot type cast float to a bigdecimal. Is contact5.getAmount() returning a float data type? Can you share the hibernate configuration for this entity as well please?

Comment: @aksappy, updated the hibernate code above.

Comment: You cannot get 17 decimal digits of precision from either a `double` or a `FLOAT`. You made the wrong decision then and you will just have to fix it now by changing the column type to `DECIMAL`.

Comment: @EJP, Agreed ! But altering column definition is like deleting the data for that column. Else Oracle wont allow to do so.

Comment: I got my own solution.Thank you guys.

Comment: Altering  the column definition is not like deleting data for that column. And you got you own solution such as what? Share it with us. This is is a community site, not a help desk.

Comment: @EJP, I have answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hibernate save an object into the database , it calls it toString method to get the value and save it. When I inspected the BigDecimal object deeply I came to know that the toString method returns exponential value and hence the value goes into the DB with a different value. For this I wrote a custom class, extending BigDecimal and override the toString method , which internally will make call to toPlanString method of BigDecimal and helps to overcome , the exponential value getting inserted will be a diferent value.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the amount column of your table Contact to a datatype of `NUMBER(19,2)`. Like

```
ALTER TABLE person
ALTER COLUMN amount NUMBER(19,2)
```